# App_Code Load Error in WebApp

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Earlier this week, recent deployments of our ASP.NET 2.0 web application started to throw the following error at unpredictable (not easily reproducible) times:

> **Parser Error**
>
> **Description**: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> **Parser Error Message**: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Code, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> **Source Error**:
>
> ```
> Line 1:  <%@ page language="c#" inherits="OurAppNamespace.Migrated_Index, App_Web_01zualsq" validaterequest="false" maxPageStateFieldLength="500" %>
> Line 2:  
> Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
> ```

Once a deployment starts throwing this error, it doesn't stop until we re-deploy or modify the Web.Config file. Needless to say, we have checked repeatedly and verified that `App_Code.dll`, version 2.5.0.0, is in the `bin` directory and has valid permissions.

We haven't made any major changes recently, and we've not made any configuration changes, so I am a bit at a loss as to how this issue arose. The cause listed in the error cannot be the problem, because the file exists. I am used to having permissions issues that result in similar errors, but changing file permissions only fixes it temporarily.

What is the actual root cause of this error, and how can we fix it?

Comment: Try turning on the Fusion log to get more information about the error.

Comment: Did you change some reference inside the App_Code.dll? If yes, check if you deploy all your references.

Comment: @AngeloBad Good suggestion, but it turns out that none of the references in App_Code.dll have changed, and all of the referenced libraries are present and also have proper permissions.

Comment: If you run the application from VS, does it work?

Comment: @AngeloBad Yes, it works consistently in Visual Studio.

Comment: mhhh.... check if you are some file inside the App_Code folder that IIS try to work with. If not, post major error details or event viewer messages.

Comment: @AngeloBad We eliminated the App_Code folder after converting to a web application. I can try to get access to the event log, but the error is usually happening on our production servers (which I don't have access to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found the problem through a process of elimination, working backwards through recent changes. It was unexpectedly important (unexpected to me, anyway) that these deployments are precompiled but updatable web applications. I contend that the ASP.NET error message was less than helpful in diagnosing the issue.

It turns out that, in the process of cleaning up the build directory by removing Visual Studio-specific files (`.sln`, `.vsmdi`, etc.), we also removed `PrecompiledApp.Config`. Because the application continued working for some time, we concluded that it was not used with the particular type of precompilation we used. Obviously, we were wrong.

Our problem was solved by restoring `PrecompiledApp.Config` to affected deployments and updating the `Web.Config` last-modified date so that IIS would pick up the change.